# Thunderbird doesn’t allow archiving some mails

Tags: email, thunderbird, archiving

Thunderbird’s [Archived Messages](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/archived-messages) feature allows to move mails into the "Archives" folder by clicking the <kbd>Archive</kbd> button or pressing the <kbd>a</kbd> key.

For some of my mails, this doesn’t work. For these mails, the button is greyed out and the key doesn’t do anything.

**What could be the reason for this? How to fix it?**

Example: I enable the Archived Messages feature for an email account that has 1200 mails in the inbox. I select all mails: the button is greyed out. I start from the top and select mails until the button is greyed out, go back one mail, archive, and repeat. From these 1200 mails, 32 can’t be archived.

I restarted Thunderbird, compacted the folder, and opened the mails, but it still doesn’t work. I also repaired the folder, didn’t help.

(Workaround: Moving the mails manually into the Archives folder works fine.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem with Thunderbird 60.6.1 (64-bit).
For me buttons are not grayed out, but behaviour is the same: message is not archived. This is what I realised after a couple of hours of investigation.

**Archiving options are bound to accounts/identities.**

Account (default identity):

1. Account Settings: `abc@email.me`
2. Copies & Folders: Message Archives

Additional identity:

1. Account Settings: `abc@email.me`
2. Manage Identites…
3. `xyz@email.me`: Edit…
4. Copies & Folders: Message Archives

Now, since we have many "archiving strateges", one for each account/identity, Thunderbird should choose one. It chooses the one of the account/identity that matches the `To:` field (or archive in Local folders if none matches).
If the IMAP folder cannot be reached the operation cannot be performed.

I have not found any documentation about it and Thunderbird gives no error message.

Several workarounds are possibile. For example, archive locally or archive on a server which is likely to be available. If you have stale unused accounts remove them (or rename them).

Comment: Your answer led me to the solution. In my case, I didn’t have multiple accounts, but multiple identities under one account. And each identity has its own 'Copies & Folders' setting. I edited your answer to include the solution for identities.

Comment: @unor, glad it was helpful and thanks for the editing.

Comment: This answer finally explained to me the issue, but it did not solve it. In version 102.12.0, the "Archive options..." menu seems to show the settings for the **default** identity, not the one I am editing. I had to select each identity as default to change its archive options from yearly to a single directory. Probably related to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1686643

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that the email provider I use (GMX) has is a limit of 20 folders. Thunderbird tried to create subfolders under "Archived" for each year; it successfully created folders 2004, 2005, ..., 2020, but failed to create any more folders after that and therefore failed to archive any emails older than 2003.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - pressing the Archive button does nothing.
Then I found out that the the problem was me manually creating a folder named Archive  and then pointing Thunderbird to it.
The proper procedure is to point to Local Folders and let Thunderbird create the Archive folder automatically. It may need a restart of ThunderBird.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to select [Select "A single folder"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Thfn.png) under "Right click on the e-mail --> Copies & Folder --> Archive options", as I already had e-mails inside the folder. I assume for the "Yearly archived folders", which is the default solution, the folder has to be empty first. I hope this helps someone.